# Which number is more near to $S$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Which number is more near to $S$?

$S=\frac{(2^3-1)(3^3-1)\dots (100^3-1)}{(2^3+1)(3^3+1)\dots (100^3+1)}$

> 1.$0.6$
>
> 2.$0.67$
>
> 3.$0.667$
>
> 4.$0.6667$

I personaly can not do anything special I have tried to calculate some easy case but no resaults any hints?

Comment: Take alook here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169588/infinite-product

Comment: @Robert Z Yes it is going to be $\frac{2}{3}$ at infinity but we don't know which one it is near when $n=100$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-solve-this-prod-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31

Comment: Using the links you finally come to the result that 
the product value for a variable upper limit $n$ is $$\frac{2}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)$$
which gives $\frac{3367}{5050}$ for $n=100$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1} &=
  \prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{(k-1)(k^2+k+1)}{(k+1)(k^2-k+1)} \\
  &= \prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{k-1}{k+1} \times \frac{k^2+k+1}{(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1} \\
  &= \left(
       \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{4}{6}  \cdot
       \ldots \cdot \frac{n-3}{n-1} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n+1}
     \right) \times \frac{n^2+n+1}{3} \\
  &= \frac{2(n^2+n+1)}{3n(n+1)} \\
 S &= \frac{2(100^2+100+1)}{3(100\times 101)} \\
   &= \frac{2}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{10100} \right) \\
   &\approx 0.6667
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

As you noted in the comments, the limit when the number of factors approaches $\infty$ is $2/3$.

Do you approach it from above or below? Which alternative is highest/lowest?

Comment: Yes, just noting the value of $\frac{S_{n+1}}{S_n}$ is enough to solve this one, provided you know the limit!